# Prevent an iFrame from redirecting to a url other than the src url

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe, sandbox

I have an iFrame that displays a 3rd party eform for our customers to fill out. After the form is submitted, the iframe displays another page that I would like to prevent from showing. I've tried using the sandbox attribute to accomplish this but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
<iframe  src="form-url"
 width="100%" height="1200px" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you can use sandbox property. Please see Pankrat's answer below. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.